# Android firebase query search title issue

Tags: android, firebase, android-viewpager, firebase-realtime-database

This is SearchActivity.java

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    /*UI*/
    private EditText mSearchText;
    private Button mSearchBtn;
    private Toolbar mSearchToolbar;

    private FragmentPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    private String value;

    private TextWatcher tw;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        mSearchText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.activity_search_search_text);
        mSearchBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.activity_search_search_btn);

        mSearchToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.activity_search_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mSearchToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);

        mSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                value = mSearchText.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "value test 1: " + value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                searchText(value);
            }
        });
    }

    private void searchText(final String value)
    {
        Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "value test 2: " + value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mPagerAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager())
        {
            private final Fragment[] mFragments = new Fragment[]
                    {
                            new FragmentSearch(value)
                    };

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position)
            {
                return mFragments[position];
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount()
            {
                return mFragments.length;
            }
        };
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.activity_search_view_pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    }
}
```

This is FragmentSearch.java

```
public class FragmentSearch extends MainFragment
{
    public String value;

    public FragmentSearch(String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().this, "value test 3: " + value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Query postsQuery = databaseReference.child("Post").orderByChild("title").equalTo(value);

        return postsQuery;
    }
}
```

This is MainFragment.java

```
public abstract class MainFragment extends Fragment
{
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder> mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView mRecycler;
    private LinearLayoutManager mManager;

    public MainFragment()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_posts, container, false);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        mRecycler = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.messages_list);
        mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mManager);

        Query postsQuery = getQuery(mDatabase);

        mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(Post.class, R.layout.item_post,
                PostViewHolder.class, postsQuery)
        {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final PostViewHolder viewHolder, final Post model, final int position)
            {
                final DatabaseReference postRef = getRef(position);

                final String postKey = postRef.getKey();
                viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
//                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PostDetailActivity.class);
//                        intent.putExtra(PostDetailActivity.EXTRA_POST_KEY, postKey);
//                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                if(model.stars.containsKey(getUid()))
                {
                    viewHolder.starView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_toggle_star_24);
                }
                else
                {
                    viewHolder.starView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_toggle_star_outline_24);
                }

                viewHolder.bindToPost(model, new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View starView)
                    {
                        DatabaseReference globalPostRef = mDatabase.child("Post").child(postRef.getKey());
                        DatabaseReference userPostRef = mDatabase.child("UserPost").child(model.uid).child(postRef.getKey());

                        onStarClicked(globalPostRef);
                        onStarClicked(userPostRef);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    private void onStarClicked(DatabaseReference postRef) {
        postRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @Override
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                Post p = mutableData.getValue(Post.class);
                if (p == null) {
                    return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                }

                if (p.stars.containsKey(getUid())) {
                    // Unstar the post and remove self from stars
                    p.starCount = p.starCount - 1;
                    p.stars.remove(getUid());
                } else {
                    // Star the post and add self to stars
                    p.starCount = p.starCount + 1;
                    p.stars.put(getUid(), true);
                }

                // Set value and report transaction success
                mutableData.setValue(p);
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                                   DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mAdapter != null)
        {
            mAdapter.cleanup();
        }
    }

    public String getUid()
    {
        return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    }

    public abstract Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference);

}
```

This is PostViewHolder.java

```
public class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView titleView;
    public TextView authorView;
    public ImageView starView;
    public TextView numStarsView;
    public TextView bodyView;

    public PostViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);

        titleView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
        authorView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_author);
        starView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.star);
        numStarsView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_num_stars);
        bodyView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_body);
    }

    public void bindToPost(Post post, View.OnClickListener starClickListener)
    {
        titleView.setText(post.title);
        authorView.setText(post.author);
        numStarsView.setText(String.valueOf(post.starCount));
        bodyView.setText(post.body);

        starView.setOnClickListener(starClickListener);
    }
}
```

This is Post.java

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Post
{
    public String uid;
    public String author;
    public String title;
    public String body;
    public int starCount = 0;
    public String type;

    public Map<String, Boolean> stars = new HashMap<>();

    public Post()
    {
    }

    public Post(String uid, String author, String title, String body, String type)
    {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
        this.body = body;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap()
    {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("uid", uid);
        result.put("author", author);
        result.put("title", title);
        result.put("body", body);
        result.put("starCount", starCount);
        result.put("stars", stars);
        result.put("type", type);

        return result;
    }

}
```

Thank you so much for reading. I created a program to search title of the posts. When I type title in the EditText then press Search button, my toast1 test, toast2 test, and toast3 test give correct and same value and it successfully lists what I want with Query. But the problem is that when I type different text in EditText after deleting the previous text then press enter, toast3 test(in FragmentSearch.java) stays the same and does not change value. So, it just gives the previous result, not changed result. Can anyone assist me with this? Thank you!

Comment: Please also add your MainFragment.java file

Comment: I just uploaded MainFragment.java. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only change the value on the `FragmentSearch` constructor. And this constructor is only called once, and not when you press Enter.

You should change your `getQuery` method to have this value as a parameter.

On your MainFragment.java:

```
public abstract Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference, String value);
```

On your FragmentSearch.java:

```
@Override
    public Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference, String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().this, "value test 3: " + value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Query postsQuery = databaseReference.child("Post").orderByChild("title").equalTo(value);

        return postsQuery;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering Rosario!, but what about Query postsQuery = getQuery(mDatabase); in my MainFragment.java class?

Comment: I put string value into getQuery(mDatabase, (anystring)), but the test 3 gives null now..